# ng-change not called when ng-checked introduced

Tags: javascript, angularjs, faceted-search

I am trying to design a facet service, the problem is whenever I select a particular facet, a new batch of facets are fetched- so I need to preserve the old set- one to show in the UI and another to make progressive queries to SOLR. If I use ng-change along with ng-checked- it works perfectly fine as long as I am working only on one kind of filter- say price_facet. The moment I click on discount facet and come back to price-filter to uncheck the earlier checked option- the ng-change isn't calling the function.

Any idea how to get it working?

```
$scope.checkExistenceFacetDict = function(param, value){
    if(facetService.checkExitenceArray(param, value)>-1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the html:

```
      <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="discount_slab in products.facet_details.discount_percentage">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="syncDiscountCheckboxes(bool, discount_slab)" ng-model="bool" ng-checked="checkExistenceFacetDict('discount_bins', discount_slab.bin_id)">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> {[{ discount_slab.name }]} ({[{ discount_slab.count }]}) </label>
      </div>
```

And

```
      <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="price_slab in products.facet_details.price">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="syncPriceFilter(bool, price_slab)" ng-model="bool" ng-checked="checkExistenceFacetDict('price_bins', price_slab.bin_id)">
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> {[{ price_slab.name }]} ({[{ price_slab.count }]}) </label>
      </div>
```

FacetService:

```
this.checkExitenceArray = function(param, value){
    var data = facet_dict[param];
    return data.indexOf(value);
};
```

FacetDictionary:

```
var facet_dict = {
                    'brands' : [],
                    'price_bins' : [],
                    'discount_bins': [],
                    'availability': false,
                    'new_products': false,
                    'on_offer': false,
                    'sort_dropdown': 'relevance'
                 }
```

Comment: `ng-checked` and `ng-model` are not meant to be used together. See docs for checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the correction- finally got it working!